# Release key selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a number of tests that I run using Selenium. I send keys for some shortcuts I need e.g. `wordSession.Keyboard.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + Keys.F4)`. This works fine for closing out of an application. However it keeps these keys held down. I tried sending it a `ReleaseKeys` e.g.  `wordSession.Keyboard.ReleaseKey(Keys.Alt);` however function does not release the keys I'm telling it to. Is there another way of doing this or am I missing something?

My code is as follows

```
            wordSession.Keyboard.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + Keys.F4 )
            wordSession.Keyboard.ReleaseKey(Keys.Alt);
            wordSession.FindElementByName("Don't Save").Click();
```

Comment: try using Actions, it has KeyDown and KeyUp function which should accommodate your requirement https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

<s>Actions action=new Actions(wordSession);</s>

action.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + Keys.F4).Build().Perform();

Looks like Alt, Shift and Ctrl are toggling keys. Try sending the KeyDown and KeyUp instead.

`action.keyDown(Keys.Alt).sendKeys(Keys.F4).keyUp(Keys.Alt).B‌​uild().perform();`

Comment: Thanks got getting back to me. However this solution hasn't worked for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: Looks like Alt, Shift and Ctrl are toggling keys. Try this: action.keyDown(Keys.Alt).sendKeys(Keys.F4).keyUp(Keys.Alt).Build().perform();

Comment: This seems to work. Can you set this question as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks a millions for that answer :)