# How to select multiple elements in Selenium (not <Select> - <Option>)

Tags: c#, list, selenium

How can I select multiple web elements from an ordered list using Selenium WebDriver in C#?

I want to do it manually, I would press Ctrl and select multiple options. I want to automate this.

Below is the sample HTML:

```
<ol id="selectable" class="ui-selectable">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">7</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">8</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">9</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">10</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">11</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-selectee">12</li>
</ol>
```

Appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: You code trials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using GetElementsByClassName()? Combined with the KeyDown command in the Actions class (See the answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43636333/release-key-selenium)) something like this may work for you...

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

var driver = new WebDriver();

var elements = driver.GetElementsByClassName("ui-state-default ui-selectee");

var action = new Actions(driver);

action.KeyDown(Keys.Control);

foreach (var element in elements)
{

    // If element properties match your selection
    element.Click()

}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it!